# Convert node into one array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array like this :

```js
const data = [
    {
        key: 1010,
        children: [
            { key: 10101, children: [] },
            {
                key: 10102,
                children: [
                    {
                        key: 1010101,
                        checked: false,
                    },
                    {
                        key: 1010102,
                        checked: false,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        key: 2020,
        children: [
            {
                key: 20201,
                children: [
                    {
                        key: 202020,
                        checked: false,
                    },
                    {
                        key: 202021,
                        checked: false,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

And I want to get a output like this :

```js
const output = {
    idsGrid: [
        {
            gridId: 10101,
            isTable: false,
        },
        {
            gridId: 10102,
            isTable: false,
        },
        {
            gridId: 1010101,
            isTable: true,
        },
        {
            gridId: 1010102,
            isTable: true,
        },
        {
            gridId: 20201,
            isTable: false,
        },
        {
            gridId: 202020,
            isTable: true,
        },
        {
            gridId: 202021,
            isTable: true,
        },
    ],
};
```

Actually, I want to map into my seconds level's arrays and extract all object and push them into only One array, with IsTable property (WHEN checked is false  ==> IsTable is TRUE)

I'm trying using recursive method but it's not working right now..

This is what I'm trying :

```js
console.log('data ==>',data)
let a = []
const v = data.map(e => {
  return e.children.map(child => {
   return  a.push({key : child.key,isTable : true})
  })
} )
```

Comment: Could you post up the code you're using so we can test with it?

Comment: Your expected output is unclear, there are 7 objects but the data only shows 4 objects with checked. Do you want the outer objects to be included? If so, what the value of isTable then?

Comment: @0stone0 I don't want to output the first level of my tree( in this case 1010 and 2020), the others objects should be outputed with IsTable : true, except those with checkable : false , the IsTable of those must be FALSE

Comment: Then how did you get 7 objects in the output?

Comment: I have 9 object with keys in my input data, we substract 1010 and 2020 and the result is 7

Comment: This is a working solution but I want to do it with recursive method 
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-frog-rfnwpb?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Do you ever have a "checked" field set to true ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's iterate the object. Or more exactly the array of objects and their children. We keep track of level so as not to include first level.

```js
const data=[{key:1010,children:[{key:10101,children:[]},{key:10102,children:[{key:1010101,checked:!1},{key:1010102,checked:!1}]}]},{key:2020,children:[{key:20201,children:[{key:202020,checked:!1},{key:202021,checked:!1}]}]}];

function do_it(data) {
  var result = [];

  function flatten_array(arr, level) {
    level = level || 0;

    arr.forEach(function(child) {
      if (level) {
        result.push({
          gridId: child.key,
          isTable: child.checked === false
        });
      }
      child.children && flatten_array(child.children, level+1)
    });
  }

  flatten_array(data)

  return {
    idsGrid: result
  }
}

var result = do_it(data);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that :

```js
public convert(data: any[]) {
    const res: { key?: number; table?: boolean; }[] = [];
    data.forEach((obj) => {
        const temp = {
            gridId: null,
            table: false,
        }
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
            switch (k) {
                case 'key':
                    temp.gridId = obj[k];
                    break;
                case 'children':
                    temp.table = true;
                    const tempRes = this.convert(obj[k]);
                    tempRes.forEach((temp) => res.push(temp));
                default:
                    break;
            }
            res.push(temp);
        })
    })
    return new Set(res);
}
```

Which will ouput :
[image]

So it's not exactly what you want since it adds a `value` field.